# Dichromate ion: Tetrahedral or bent?

Tags: molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

I am currently studying about the vespr theory and I'm stuck on an ion which is dichromate (VI) ion $\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$. So this is what I am thinking about:

1) If I make the oxygen atom at the middle the centre atom, it is a bent.
2) If I make the chromium atom thecentre atom, it is a tetrahedral.

So, my problem is that whether dichromate (VI) ion bent or tetrahedral?

Comment: Well, the overall shape of the molecule doesn't get anything close to bent and/or tetrahedral. I suggest doing some readings about hybridization and MO basics, rather than sticking to *most-beloved, most-loathed* VSEPR.

Comment: I am going to start reading about hybridization after Vespr

Comment: @MARamezani The VSEPR model should be digested in a very careful way - it predicts some molecular shapes correctly for the entirely wrong reasons. And for those reasons it is also often very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, Bent about Oxygen and tetrahedral about chromium:

$\hskip2.5in$[image]

Comment: So, how do I call it? Tetrahedral bent?

Comment: @Simon-Nail-It nothing nothing I suppose